# mod_python does not process multiple requests from the same browser simultaneously for the same file

Tags: apache, blocking, mod-python, serial-processing

I have a page which can take long time to process. But in the mean time if the same page is accessed (from the same system), the second instance gets blocked till the first page finishes. Actually instead of the blocking behaviour, I would be happy it the second instance fails rather than getting hung. Is there a way to around to make the same file accessbile at the same time.

I have found the same problem being present in PHP also. But those replies were related to PHP. [Apache same orgin request blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973453/apache-same-orgin-request-blocking) [Why does apache not process multiple requests from the same browser simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623484/why-does-apache-not-process-multiple-requests-from-the-same-browser-simultaneous) discusses about the same problem with php.